# How to type cast in C# having needed type as System.Type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I need to initialize an instance of `System.Collections.Generic.List<String>` using Reflection. For example, the type name has been loaded from XML, and it is unknown before the program has launched. I got the type and its assembly:

```
Type T = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]");
Assembly ass = T.Assembly;
```

After this I need to initialize my variable, but I don't want to write the type explicitly, so using:

```
var lst = ass.CreateInstance(T.FullName) as List<String>;
```

is inapropriate. I have already got the required type in T, so if I can do something like:

```
var lst = ass.CreateInstance(T.FullName) as T;
```

it should be fine. But I can't.
What do I have to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with lst? Answer depends on that.

Comment: You simply can't do that. `T` is only known at run time, but the type on the right side of `as` needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: I want to use it the way if it was explicitly initialized as `List<String> lst = new List<String>();`

Comment: Since you don't want to specify the type, the *lst* variable needs to be of type *object* or *dynamic*.

Comment: I guess the type is known at runtime only. If that's the case then use `dynamic lst = Activator.CreateInstance(T);`

Comment: @gp: please don't suggest dynamic unless it's strictly needed. object will suffice here.

Comment: @siride is dynamic usage can cause failures?

Comment: @siride with dynamic, you can still access methods if you know it already. Roman, using dynamic could cause runtime errors if you access any method on the object which does not exist at runtime.

Comment: @gp: it adds overhead and is also a way for bad design decisions to be papered over. If you already know which methods you will be calling on the object, then just use that type, or an appropriate interface. If you don't, then you better not do anything with the object other than pass it around. This is why we have static typing in the first place.

Comment: @siride totally agree with your points. But dynamic didn't come for aiding to design but to ease development in specific scenarios. it has it's own benefits but surely until you need them you should not compromise on your design.

Comment: @gp dynamic came along to help with Office integration and to support dynamically-typed language running on the CLR. People should keep that in mind when suggesting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to declare a variable of a 'variable' type. Any variable/property/method/parameter/class/whatever MUST be know beforehand, at compile-time, since C# is a strongly- typed language.

The only real way to deal with dynamically generated data types like in your example is to stay with the type-unsafe `object` or `dynamic`, which can contain anything, even unknown at compile-time.
Also remember that the `var`syntax isn't anything variable really, it's just syntax sugar for avoiding writing the real type, which is obtained from the type on the right side of the `=`, so it's really of no help for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is appropriate for me.